# How to read an sqllite database file in a Jetpack Compose Desktop project configured for SQLDelight?

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

I'm trying to read a pre-built sqllite database in jetpack compose desktop project which is configured for SQLDelight. All I could find on the internet is the Android version of the compose. I tried putting the database file in the resources folder, but I don't know how the reading part is done. Please help me. Thanks in advance.